# Dynamic, cross database trigger creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to dynamically create a number of triggers across two databases but I am having problems with the Create Trigger statement when switching databases

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT Name FROM ' + @DB + '.sys.triggers WHERE Name = ' + '''' 
           + @Table + '_DELTATrigger' + ''''
EXEC(@SQL)

IF @@RowCount > 0   
BEGIN
  SET @SQL = 'USE ' + @DB + '; DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[' + @Table + '_DELTATrigger]'
  EXEC(@SQL)
END

SET @SQL = 'CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[' + @Table + '_DELTATrigger] 
                ON [dbo].[' + @Table + '] 
                AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
                AS 
                BEGIN 
                  SET NOCOUNT ON 
                  UPDATE [' + @Table + '] 
                  SET [Delta] = 1 
                  FROM inserted 
                  WHERE inserted.[ID] = [' + @Table + '].[ID] 
                END;'               
EXEC (@SQL)
```

If I run this statement I get the following issue

> *Error 8197, Level 16, State 4, Procedure tblBuild_DataPlate_DELTATrigger, Line 1
>
>   Message: The object 'dbo.tblBuild_DataPlate' does not exist or is 
>   invalid for this operation.*

Changing the dynamic create trigger to include the USE  statement does not work as the Create Trigger has to be the first statement

```
SET @SQL = 'USE ' + @DB + '; CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[' + @Table + '_DELTATrigger]
            ON [dbo].[' + @Table + '] 
            AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
            AS 
            BEGIN 
              SET NOCOUNT ON 
              UPDATE [' + @Table + '] 
              SET [Delta] = 1 
              FROM inserted 
              WHERE inserted.[ID] = [' + @Table + '].[ID] 
            END;'               
EXEC (@SQL)

Error 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure -, 
Line 1, Message: 'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first 
statement in a query batch.
```

You can not fully qualify the object with the database in this case as you get the following error

> *Error 166, Level 15, State 1, Procedure -, Line 1,
>
>   Message: 'CREATE/ALTER TRIGGER' does not allow 
>   specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.*

Is there a dynamic way around this?

Comment: Did you try  CREATE TRIGGER ' + DBName +'[dbo].[' + @Table + '_DELTATrigger] ?

Comment: Yes. The third error (above) occurs, you can't have the DB prefix in the Create Trigger query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code below will run the `sp_executesql` on the selected database (@DB), so with this, you can create the trigger on the rigth place:

```
SET @SQL = 'EXEC ' + @DB + '..sp_executesql N''
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[' + @Table + '_DELTATrigger] 
                            ON [dbo].[' + @Table + '] 
                            AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
                        AS 
                        BEGIN 
                            SET NOCOUNT ON 

                        END;'''               
            EXEC (@SQL)
```